# Spark 1.6 and hadoop 2.3 where to set socketTimeOut for s3?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, socket-timeout-exception

We are getting socket timeouts during reads from s3. Documentation around increasing the socketTimeOut is not obvious. Would appreciate any help on this.

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.read(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:198)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:178)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:200)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.close(ContentLengthInputStream.java:103)
at org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity.streamClosed(BasicManagedEntity.java:164)
at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.checkClose(EofSensorInputStream.java:227)
at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.close(EofSensorInputStream.java:174)
at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.consume(EntityUtils.java:88)
at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.HttpMethodReleaseInputStream.releaseConnection(HttpMethodReleaseInputStream.java:102)
at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.HttpMethodReleaseInputStream.close(HttpMethodReleaseInputStream.java:194)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem$NativeS3FsInputStream.seek(NativeS3FileSystem.java:152)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an option to set socket timeouts in S3n. Note also that the stack trace shows that the client is attempting to read to the end of the file as it tries to close() the stream before reopening it at a different location. Again, a known limitation of some jets3t versions, hence s3n. This will not be fixed in Hadoop as all dev is taking place on S3a, based on the AWS library.

Please, update to a later version of the Hadoop JARs (2.7.x) and use s3a.